# $data = $query->row(); returns only one row

Tags: sql, codeigniter, row

Im trying to list the results of my sql query (picking up all the movies from a category), but I cannot figure out how to get all the rows instead of only one.

Here's the code :

```
     $this->load->database();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM movies WHERE category = "'.$movies_category.'";';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    $data = $query->row();
    $this->response($data, 200);
```

I've tried :

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $data = $query->row();
    }
    $this->response($data, 200);
```

And it doesn't work. Any suggestion ? Thank you !

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html and http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Comment: If you run the same query in the MySQL Console do you get results back?

Comment: And the 2nd set of code, you'd never use a mix of built in and native mysql functions like that.

Comment: $data = $query->row(); only return row..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->load->database();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM movies WHERE category = "'.$movies_category.'";';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);

$data = $query->result();
```

To traverse the `$data` array:

```
foreach($data AS $row)
{
    //to retrieve the data from each row.
    $col1 = $row->col1;
    $col2 = $row->col2;
}
```

Use `result()` instead of `row()`. `result()` will return an array of objects that are your results. Alternatively, you can use`result_array()` which will resturn an array of arrays keyed according to your columns. Please refer to [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) for a better outline of the `result()` and `row()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a database configuration file? the load->database() [requires it](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html). Where is $movies_category coming from? This will let you iterate over your results.

```
$this->load->database();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM movies WHERE category = "'.$movies_category.'";';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->column;
}
```

Where column corresponds with one of the values in the movies table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned the potential hazards of using variables (possibly user input) in your SQL. You should seriously consider using query bindings or the active record features of CodeIgniter to build safer queries.

Consider the following solution to your problem:

```
$this->load->database();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM movies WHERE category = ?';
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($movies_category));

// $data = $query->result(); // returns result as an array of objects
$data = $query->result_array(); // returns result as array
$this->response($data, 200);
```

I'm assuming this is for some sort of API? If so, consider using the result_array() method as it will probably be better suited for your needed output, and also really easy to convert into JSON:

```
$json_data = json_encode($data);
```

Hope that helps,
Cheers.

Comment: Yes it was for an API. Many thanks, it solved my problem and I'm understanding better now.

Answer (score 0):

For your question row() return only one value its good for checking in ID and if you want get all the rows use result_array() or simple result()

You can try this code....

```
    Model: 
    function get_movies($movies_category){
      $this->db->where("category",$movies_category);
      $query = $this->db->get("movies");
      return $query->result_array();
    }

    Controller:
    $this->data['movies'] = $this->'name of model'->get_movies('here is the movie categories');

    View:
    foreach($movies as $m){
    print_r($m);
    }
    exit();
```

Note you can directly add the code in function in model to controller add this in your controller if you want directly...

```
$this->data['movies] = $this->db->get('movies')->result_array();
```